# LDAP認証を達成したいが、拡張dllが作用していないのかPHPINFOにLDAP定義が現れない

Tags: php

PHPのVerは7.0.26です。こちらはWindowsServer2012（64bit）で利用のため、昨日PHPのサイトから入手してきたものです。

拡張dllの収まったフォルダ=extには、当初からldap認証を達成するためのdll（php_ldap.dll）が格納されていました。
（個別に入手したわけでなく上記作業でextフォルダに収まっていた）
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

尚、こちらの利用を確実にするため、php.iniの定義ファイル上で、拡張フォルダの所在をフルパス（C:\Program Files\PHP\ext）で記載しなおしています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
この所在の指定は問題ないとみえ、自らSQLServer接続のためMicrosoftから入手したdllは（extフォルダに格納：PDO drivers=sqlsrv、またOracle接続のために定義・配置したdll、OCI8も表示されている）PHPINFOのPDO枠にしっかり現れています。

ところが、標題のとおり、LDAPの定義がPHPINFOに現れてきません。
案の定、LDAPの関数を利用したWebページで、関数未定義のエラー（Undefined function ldap_connect）を招きます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

====質問====
Apacheの再起動は繰り返していますが一向にPHPINFOへ、LDAPの定義が表れてこない理由、対策をご教示頂けないでしょうか。

年末のご多忙な時期ですがよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 文字の情報はなるべく「文字」で載せるようにしてください。キャプチャ画像にしてしまうと検索や引用が難しくなります。

Comment: @cubick 　ご指摘をありがとうございます、本文に加筆を図りました。ご確認頂ければ幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

皆様　あけましておめでとうございます、本件が無事解決を迎えましたので一応にご報告申し上げます。

PHPの動作環境を整える上で、現在動作させようとしているのは64bit版ですが、以前環境構築に試行錯誤していた際、32bit版をサイトから取得して設定を進めていた時期があったのです。

この時ちょっと記憶にないのですが、システム環境変数に
C:\Program Files (x86)\PHPを記載していたようでした。（php拡張子の関連付け？？）

本日PHPinfoのenviroment定義を舐めるようにみて気がつき、早速こちらを修正=環境変数のパスから現在PHPフォルダが配置された正規パス　つまり(x86)の文字を除去してみると．．．
無事LDAPのdllが読み込まれるようになりました。

phpinfoにldapの定義が表れ、Webページの動作も無事行えるようになりました。

お騒がせして大変申し訳ございませんでした。重ねてお詫び申し上げます。
また別の機会で皆様のご支援を頂けましたら幸いでございます。

本年もよろしくお願い申し上げます。